# Need Asssitance Finding Fortan Code for Time Series Decomposition STL

Tags: time-series, fortran, decomposition, loess

The article 'STL: A Seasonal-Trend Decomposition Procedure Based on Loess' by Cleveland 1990 on p.31 para 6.6 states that the Fortran code is available by sending an email to netlib@research.att.com
However, this email address does not exist anymore.
Does anybody know how to obtain the 'stl' and 'dloess' Fortran code?

Comment: If I google "dloess fortran" I find https://www.netlib.org/a/ - is this of use?

Comment: Ian,

Thank you. This does indeed lead to the Fortran code. It is however badly formatted and hence difficult to read but it will work.

Many thanks,

Filiep